# Copy-item exclude Sub-folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Trying to get my copy-item to copy everything in directory except a subfolder. I was able to exclude in the folder and files, but not subfolders.

I tried using get-children and the -exclude in the copy-item but didn't exclude them as I hope

```
$exclude = "folder\common"

Get-ChildItem "c:\test" -Directory | 
    Where-Object{$_.Name -notin $exclude} | 
    Copy-Item -Destination 'C:\backup' -Recurse -Force
```

Hoping that the common folder will exist but nothing in it would be copy.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `{$_.Name -notin $exclude}` -> `{$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude} `

Comment: Tried that, but It didn't exclude the common folder

Comment: `$exclude` needs to be regex escaped if you are using regex matching (`-match` or `-notmatch`). `$exclude = [regex]::Escape("folder\common")` or manually escape the \ with \\.

Comment: @AdminOfThings I tried both of those and it seem like it didn't exclude the folder

Comment: If $exclude = "folder", it would be much easier.

Comment: Depth parameter might help you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this should do what you need:

```
$sourceFolder = 'C:\test'
$destination  = 'C:\backup'
$exclude      = @("folder\common")  # add more folders to exclude if you like

# create a regex of the folders to exclude
# each folder will be Regex Escaped and joined together with the OR symbol '|'
$notThese = ($exclude | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Recurse -File | 
     Where-Object{ $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $notThese } | 
     ForEach-Object {
        $target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourceFolder.Length)
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $target -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $target -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
        }
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $target -Force
     }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I did switch to .Fullname from .DirectoryName. For some cases where I wanted a specific filename but minor change

Comment: You said you could add more folders to exclude, what would the syntax be for that?

Comment: @Branderson20 Just add foldernames or bits of folderpaths to the `$exclude` array. Something like `$exclude = "folder\common", "folder\notsocommon", "donttouchthisfolder"`

Comment: Thanks, was another issue but solved it, thanks though

Comment: Is there a way to add a date stamp onto the new folder name?

Comment: @glass_kites You mean something like `$target = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath ('{0}_{1:yyyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourceFolder.Length), (Get-Date))` ? Sure.

Comment: I'd rather write a C# console app to do that, which is easy to debug and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the `-exclude` parameter on `Get-ChildItem` would work:

```
$exclude = 'Exclude this folder','Exclude this folder 2','Folder3'

Get-ChildItem -Path "Get these folders" -Exclude $exclude | Copy-Item -Destination "Send folders here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
$exclude= 'subfolderA'
$path = 'c:\test'

$fileslist = gci $path -Recurse

foreach ($i in 0..$fileslist){  if( -not ($i.Fullname -like "*$($exlusion)*")){ copy-item -path $i.fullname -Destination 'C:\backup'  -Force  } }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for subfolders, I want to exclude folderA\subFolderA

Comment: Well that just checking everything folder for the filename, but the edge case might come up if it needs to be more specific then that

Comment: this would work for all sub folders in the excluded folders  because the 'full name' contains the parent folder name in it, thus exclusion.