# Exclude multiple folders from get-childitem

Tags: powershell, directory, scripting, copy, compare

I have this script that compares 2 directories with each other if it matches it copies it to the other directory. But i need 2 folders to be excluded on the source folder because there are old files there. I excluded one folder but i can't add an second one. Can someone help me out? (I'm a beginner in Powershell) I know the foreach loop is empty, this is for testing purposes.

```
$aDir = "C:\Replace TEST SCRIPT\A"
$bDir = "C:\Replace TEST SCRIPT\Y"

$aFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$bDir\" -Exclude "Folder1","Folder2" | Get-ChildItem -Path "$bDir\*.pdf" -Recurse -File | select -exp FullName
ForEach ($file in $aFiles) {
    $laatste = (Get-Item $file).LastWriteTime
    $filenaam = Split-Path -Path "$file" -Leaf
    if(Test-Path -Path "C:\Replace TEST SCRIPT\A\$filenaam") {
        Write-Output "$filenaam exists in $aDir. Copying."         
        Copy-Item -Path "$file" -Recurse -Destination "$aDir" 
    } else {        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy-item exclude Sub-folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858059/copy-item-exclude-sub-folders)

Comment: I'ts not a subfolder, it is just a folder in $bDir

Comment: Then why the title _Exclude multiple folders_. If a folder is inside another folder, then... it **IS** a subfolder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
$aFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$bDir\" -Exclude "PDF","folder2" | Get-ChildItem -filter "*.pdf" -Recurse -File | select -exp FullName
```

Btw.
There is already a post to your certain question:
[How can I exclude multiple folders using Get-ChildItem -exclude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude)

Please take a look at it and let us know.

Comment: I saw this post, but i wasn't able to build it in. Because i need multiple excludes, maybe one you can show me how to do it with my script?

Comment: I edited my post and added the get-childitem line. Does this work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion really appreciate it!,but i get an error.. I posted it down in my original post!

Comment: I don't see any error message in your post? What do you mean with "original post"?

Comment: I changed it. Is it working now? If not, can you send me the error message?

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it worked. Have a nice day ;)